# Bash Scripting: Using $( to assign variables

Tags: bash

I am having the worst time with setting a variable in a bash shell using the $( format.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

var= date
echo $var

hrs="NA"
min="NA"
t="AM"
hr=12

var= date | grep -o [0-9][0-9]':'[0-9][0-9]
echo $var

if echo $var | grep -q [0-9][0-9] | > 12
then

echo $hrs
hrs=$(echo $var | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]")
echo $hrs
hrs="$hrs-$hr"
fi

echo $hrs

if $var | grep -q [0-9][0-9] | > 12
then
    t="PM"
fi

echo $t
```

However when I echo the hrs variable afterwards it is an empty string. Can someone explain where I am going wrong with my assignment? I know that I am entering the if statement so I do not think that is the problem.

Comment: You have several errors in this code. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `var= date` must be `var=date` etc.

Comment: @Fredrik: More likely it needs backticks (which I'm too lazy to figure out how to render in a comment).

Comment: In several places, you seem to be missing backticks and/or quotation marks. Please copy-and-paste the *exact* contents of your script *and* its output into your question. Without that, we can only guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KeithThompson - you're right, I was merely refering to the space after the `=`-sign. `$(...)` is prefered over backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
if [ $(echo "$var" | grep -q [0-9][0-9]) -ge 12 ]
then
    hrs=$(echo "$var" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]")
fi
```

In your code you should change

```
var= date | grep -o [0-9][0-9]':'[0-9][0-9]
#   ^                         ^ ^
```

for

```
var=$(date | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')
#   ^^               ^                     ^^
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track for figuring out the OP's question, but why backticks in one place and `$()` in the other?  `grep -q` isn't going to work with `-ge`, either.

Comment: Good point. I just copied the original code with $( and then added my part with backsticks. I prefer backsticks

Comment: You really should have quotes around the entire regexp; if you happen to have files with names like `12:34` in your current directory `[0-9][0-9]':'[0-9][0-9]` will expand to a list of matching files. I just fixed it.